# Bean definition and dependency injection in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I'm migrating from Spring to Java EE.

How can I define a bean with the aim to perform the DI by using the `@Inject` annotation?

For instance, in Spring, I've a bean definition as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class MailSenderConfig {

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine getVelocityEngine() throws VelocityException,
            IOException {
        VelocityEngineFactory factory = new VelocityEngineFactory();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("resource.loader", "class");
        props.put("class.resource.loader.class",
                "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader."
                        + "ClasspathResourceLoader");
        factory.setVelocityProperties(props);
        return factory.createVelocityEngine();
    }

    // ...

}
```

I can `@Autowired` it into another class.

I'd like to do the same in Java EE.

Comment: Just annotate the bean with `@Named` or create a factory with `@Produces`.